# How do I change the size of the polygon that is called from a text file?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having a problem with changing the size of a polygon that I am calling from a text file using vertices. Whenever I try and change the coordinates of the vertices in the text file and run the program the shape stays the same size and when I go back to the text file all the coordinates have changed back. How can I change the shapes size?

Here is the code I'm using for this:

```
void cal_vertices() {
    // open a file for writing pentagon vertices 
    ofstream outfile("vertices1.txt");
    float a = 2 * 3.1415926 / 5.0;
    float x1 = 0.0, y1 = 1.0;
    outfile << x1 << " " << y1 << endl;;
    float x, y;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        x = x1 * cos(a * i) - y1 * sin(a * i);
        y = y1 * cos(a * i) + x1 * sin(a * i);
        outfile << x << " " << y << endl;;
    }
    outfile.close();
}

void read_vertices() {
    //reads verticies from the text file
    ifstream infile("vertices1.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        infile >> vertices[i][0];
        infile >> vertices[i][1];
        cout << vertices[i][0] << " " << vertices[i][1] << endl;
    }
}

void init(){

    cal_vertices();
    read_vertices();

    glNewList(listname, GL_COMPILE);
    glColor4f(red, green, blue, 1.0);

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        glVertex3f(vertices[i][0], vertices[i][1], 0.0);

    }
    glEnd();
    glEndList();
```

Comment: It's probably a good idea to avoid phrases like "calling polygons" in this context. I was going to say that's a meaningless thing to say and then I saw that you were using display lists. It's still very unclear, but at least not completely meaningless :) Matrix transformations exist for this purpose, in particular scaling matrices. Those are part of the version of OpenGL you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
glPushMatrix ();
  glScalef (2.0F, 2.0F, 2.0F);
  glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    ...
  glEnd();
glPopMatrix ();
```

That should double the size of your polygon in each dimension.